# Needing an if/else statement in SQL Update Case

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, case

How can I update multiple records in a database using one Update statement where the cases are different.

```
refundNumber = CASE _
WHEN salesRecords.invNo='1' AND itemNo='250' AND length(refundNumber) > 1 THEN _
concat(refundNumber, ', 88' ) Else '88' _
WHEN salesRecords.invNo='1' AND itemNo='7095' AND length(refundNumber) > 1 THEN _
concat(refundNumber, ', 88' ) Else '88'  _
END
```

This fails and should look like:

```
refundNumber = CASE _
WHEN invNo='1' AND itemNo='250' AND length(refundNumber) > 1 THEN _
concat(refundNumber, ', 88' )  _
WHEN invNo='1' AND itemNo='7095' AND length(refundNumber) > 1 THEN _
concat(refundNumber, ', 88' ) Else '88'  _
END
```

The difference being that the Else comes right at the end.

But it sets `refundNumber` on ALL records to 88.

What I am trying to do is add a value to a field named `refundNumber` to those items where the `invNo = 'currentInvoiceNumber'` AND `itemNo = 'itemNumber'`

BUT, since `refundNumber` is a text field which is meant to contain a comma separated list, I am trying to determine whether this field is empty or not, if it is, just enter the number, if it isn't, append the number preceded by a comma to the existing field content. Hence the `length(refundNumber) > 1 THEN  concat(refundNumber, ', 88' )` bit.

I've not tested it, but I believe the VB logic I'd need would be:

```
IF invNo='1' And itemNo='250' THEN
    IF length(refundNumber) > 1 THEN 
        concat(refundNumber, ', 88' )  
    ELSE
        '88'
    END IF
ELSE IF invNo='1' And itemNo='7095' THEN        
    IF length(refundNumber) > 1 THEN 
        concat(refundNumber, ', 88' )  
    ELSE
        '88'
    END IF
Else
    refundNumber '- leave the field value as is because it does not comply with any of the above conditions
END IF
```

How could I translate this to an `SQL CASE` string?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a nested CASE?

Comment: Oh, um, I guess because I havent thought of it! I'm not good with CASE statements they always confuse my head!

Comment: I am just asking, because your VB equivalent is also nested...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to update records where the InvNo is not '1' and the itemNo is not '250' or '7095' why not have a where clause limiting the set to this criteria? Then all you need to do concatenate refund number and 88 using a case expression, but you don't even need this you could use:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET refundNumber = ISNULL(CONCAT(NULLIF(refundNumber, ''), ', 88'), '88')
WHERE InvNo = '1'
AND itemNo in ('250', '7095')
```

Or use a nested case expression?

Comment: Ah! That's how you do it! I never really worked out how to properly put a where clause into a multi-line update! I'll try this properly tomorrow, but it looks exactly what I need, and less confusing than nesting. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason that wouldn't work, but using CASE with the additional `WHERE in` did! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
refundNumber = CASE _
WHEN invNo='1' AND itemNo='250' THEN _
    CASE WHEN length(refundNumber) > 1 THEN concat(refundNumber, ', 88' )  _
    ELSE '88' END
WHEN invNo='1' AND itemNo='7095' THEN _
    CASE WHEN length(refundNumber) > 1 THEN concat(refundNumber, ', 88' ) _
    Else '88' END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you gotta do it with case, try this, but GarethD's answer using the WHERE clause is probably better

```
refundNumber = CASE WHEN (invNo='1' AND itemNo='250')
                Or (invNo='1' AND itemNo='7095')
                THEN
                   CASE WHEN length(refundNumber) > 1 
                   THEN concat(refundNumber, ', 88' )
                   ELSE '88'
                   END
                ELSE refundnumber
           END
```